# Help with a $z$-transfrom Problem

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

I have the function $$(1-e^{-2n})u[n-1]$$ where $u[n]$ is the step input.

I want to find the $z$-transform for this function. I know that the transform of $1-e^{-2n}$ will be $$\frac{z}{z-1} - \frac{z}{z-e^{-2}}$$ Now do I shift each element by one unit to the left to get the entire $z$-transform?

Comment: Is it a discrete or continuous signal? Please try to use the appropriate notation (and don't use $*$ for multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

You might rewrite your signal as

$$x(t)=(1-e^{-2t})u(t-1)=(1-e^{-2t})u(t)-(1-e^{0})\delta(t)=(1-e^{-2t})u(t)$$

The idea is to express the signal $x(t)$ as the difference of two signals. The first signal has the step function starting at $t=0$, and the second function removes the contribution of the step at the sample $t=0$. In your case, even the function has $x(0)=0$, so it does not matter, if you have the step function starting at $t=0$ or $t=1$. So, you can just apply your solution above and you have it.

To explain my steps in a bit more detail: First note, that 
$$u(t)=u(t-1)+\delta(t).$$(we are in a discrete setting with $t\in\mathbb{Z}$). Therefore $$u(t-1)=u(t)-\delta(t).$$ Let's insert this into your signal (we take a general $h(t)$. In your case you'd have $h(t)=1-\exp(-2t)$:

$$x(t)=h(t)u(t-1)=h(t)(u(t)-\delta(t))=h(t)u(t)-h(t)\delta(t)$$

The last part, i.e. $h(t)\delta(t)$ becomes equal to $h(0)\delta(t)$ due to the sifting property of the Dirac. So, in general you have

$$\mathcal{Z}\{h(t)u(t-1)\}=\mathcal{Z}\{h(t)u(t)\}-\mathcal{Z}\{h(0)\delta(t)\}=H(z)-h(0),$$

where $H(z)$ is the Z-transform of $h(t)$, and we assume that $h(t)$ is causal, i.e. $h(t)=h(t)u(t)$. (This property is implicitely assumed in the standard Z-transform).

In your case, you have $h(0)=0$, so the second term vanishes.

Comment: I don't really understand how you are breaking it into these two terms? why do you have the second term with t=0 and the impulse function, isn't the impulse function at equal to infinity? Is there a name for this property you are using?

Comment: I've added some more information on how I did achieve this. I dont think there is a special name for this technique.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the $z$-transform of $$f[n]=(1-a^n)u[n-1]$$ where $a=e^{-2}$. We can re-write it as

$$u[n-1]-a\cdot a^{(n-1)}u[n-1]$$
We can use the following property of the $z$-transform

> $$\mathcal{Z}\{x[n-n_0]\}=z^{-n_0}X(z)$$

Since $\mathcal{Z}\{u[n]\}=\frac{z}{z-1},|z|>1$, we have $$\mathcal{Z}\{u[n-1]\}=\frac{z^{-1}z}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z-1},|z|>1$$
and similarly, since $\mathcal{Z}\{a^nu[n]\}=\frac{z}{z-a},|z|>a$, we have 
 $$\mathcal{Z}\{a^{n-1}u[n-1]\}=\frac{z^{-1}z}{z-a}=\frac{1}{z-a},|z|>a$$Therefore, the overall $z$-transform is

$$\boxed{F(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{e^{-2}}{z-e^{-2}},|z|>1}$$